# entering data into specific webpage using VBA

Tags: vba, text, input

I am trying to input the date into a website using VBA. I cant seem to do it as it keeps coming up with object error.

I cant seem to input the number in the period dropdown either

can somebody help?

```
Sub DataStuff()
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUData"
ie.Visible = True
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

ie.Document.getElementByID("param6").Value = "5"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements you are trying to interact with are in a frame.  The source code shows the frame name as "topFrame".  It also provides an url for the frame as

http://bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_PanBMUTop

If you navigate to the url for the frame, then code like

ie.Document.getElementByID("param6").Value = "5"

will work.

Comment: Thanks, so subtle change but i didnt see that. Cheers :D